# How to create an array of hashes by mapping 2 hashes in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Ruby on Rails application. I want to combine 2 array of hashes with hash and to result in array of hashes.

Inputs:

```
first_array_of_hash = [{:name => "John", :age => 34, :mode => "nullable"},{:name => "Rose", :age => 30, :mode => "nullable"}]

second_hash = {:field_name => "", :field_age => nil, :field_nullable => false, :field_default => ""}
```

I want my result to be like below

```
result = [{:field_name => "John", :field_age => 34, :field_nullable => true, :field_default => ""},{:field_name => "Rose", :field_age => 30, :field_nullable => true, :field_default => ""}]
```

Comment: What's the logic here? `:name` becomes `:field_name` in the result? so it's like a template?

Comment: That's the requirement for my application.

Comment: what's `yes` and `no`? are those variables?

Comment: yes and no are strings. Based on the value of "nullable" column, I set field_nullable

Comment: they don't look like strings, the code that you gave results in an error

Comment: I have updated it to strings now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210370/discussion-between-galet-and-jack).

Comment: I understand why `:field_nullable=>true` for Jack, but not why `:field_nullable=>false` for Rose, considering that `:mode => "nullable"` for both of them. Please explain or, if that’s an error in your example, correct it.

Comment: corrected it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular `Array#map` for this:

```rb
first_array_of_hash = [{:name => "John", :age => 34, :nullable => 'yes'},{:name => "Rose", :age => 30, :nullable => 'no'}]

second_hash = {:field_name => "", :field_age => nil, :field_nullable => false, :field_default => ""}

def transform(object)
  {
    field_name: object[:name],
    field_age: object[:age],
    field_nullable: object[:mode] == 'nullable'
  }
end

result = first_array_of_hash.map do |object|
  second_hash.merge(transform(object))
end

puts result
```